# Does @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) inject new mocks for members annotated with @Mock prior to each test?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

...or does it do it only once, before any test has been run?

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class Tests {
  @Mock
  private ISomething mockedSomething;

  @Test
  public void test1() {
    // Is the value of mockedSomething here
  }

  @Test
  public void test2() {
    // ... guaranteed to be either the same or a different instance here?  Or is it indeterminate?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PowerMockRunner`, like most JUnit runners, creates [a brand new test class instance for every test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14010222/1426891). This helps ensure that tests don't interfere with one another.

The PowerMock source is a little hard to follow, with per-JUnit-version delegates and classloader-conserving "chunks", but you can see [here in PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl:189](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/source/browse/trunk/modules/module-impl/junit4/src/main/java/org/powermock/modules/junit4/internal/impl/PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java#189) that every time `invokeTestMethod` is called it gets a new instance from `createTest`, which gets it from `createTestInstance`.

PowerMock then populates the new instance with fresh mocks. The documentation for `@Mock` injection is a little tricky to find, but I found some on the [PowerMock TestListeners wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/TestListeners). As it turns out, the `AnnotationEnabler` class varies by support library—[this is the Mockito one, for instance](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/source/browse/trunk/api/mockito/src/main/java/org/powermock/api/extension/listener/AnnotationEnabler.java)—but both re-inject fresh mocks on `beforeTestMethod`.

Note that static fields will likely be conserved between tests, so though instance fields will be populated freshly for every test method, static fields will not. Avoid using mutable static fields in your tests, whether or not you use PowerMock.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was aware that runner create new classes for each run.  But what I'm wondering is: "though instance fields will be populated freshly for every test method" is that guaranteed by the contract of the JUnit runner?  Or does it just happen to be the case with some/most/this runners?  And is the @Mock injection is also redone, since this isn't a "normal" field?  I suppose if it isn't it'll just be null, or instance-identical to the other one, which I can keep around in a static in a different class and check...  I will have to try writing some more test code.

Comment: @Tom I've updated the answer. One can imagine a JUnit runner that violates the convention and conserves instances, but it would be breaking convention. I hedged my bets with "should" originally, for lack of primary-source support, but I've since found it and can say for sure where and how the mocks are injected before every test method.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  This sort of documentation is exactly what I was hoping to find.  I also modified my tests to track @Mock instances and confirmed it is working as promised.